# Add samples randomly from different datasets to retrieve a final dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am not sure if the following is possible using `tf.data.Dataset` but imagine the following:

There is a dataset A and B which I would like to load using `tf.data.Dataset`, however, I would like to randomly combine (add) samples from A and B.

Basically, this is what I want:

```
sample = A.random_sample() + B.random_sample()
```

The question is whether this can be done in Tensorflow.

```
A = tf.data.Dataset('/data/a/*')
B = tf.data.Dataset('/data/b/*')

final_dataset = # <-- random_a + random_b
```

Comment: Reading @bit01's answer now I wonder: What do you mean by *"combine samples"*? Does the `+` in your comment mean appending the two datasets, or actually adding the values together?

Comment: @GPhilo it was actually about adding. I edited my question to mention that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: since the question isn't clear on the meaning of "combine", here's both versions

### IF you want to mix two subsets extracted from `A` and `B`:

Very easy to do with [tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets)

```
NUM_A = 42
NUM_B = 24

A = ... #load and preprocess your A data as a tf.data.Dataset (shuffle too, if necessary)
B = ... #load and preprocess your B data as a tf.data.Dataset (shuffle too, if necessary)

final_dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([A.take(NUM_A),B.take(NUM_B)] seed=42) # seed is for repeatability
```

---

### IF you actually want to add the samples from the two datasets:

Also very easy, with `shuffle`, 'zip' and `map`:

```
BUF_SIZE = 1000 # arbitrary number chosen just for this example
A = ... #load and preprocess your A data as a tf.data.Dataset
B = ... #load and preprocess your B data as a tf.data.Dataset
A = A.shuffle(BUF_SIZE, seed=42) # seeds for repeatability
B = B.shuffle(BUF_SIZE, seed=43)
final_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip([A,B]).map(lambda a,b: a+b)
# possibly add a .repeat() for multiple epochs
```

In this case, shuffling separately A and B is what provides the random combination. Repeating at the end (plus the default True value for `shuffle_every_iteration` in `shuffle()`) ensure that at each new epoch you get a new random combination in `final_dataset`.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function where you can implement your logic of fusion between two dataset in generator function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [5, 6, 7, 8]

db1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(A).shuffle(len(A))
db2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(B).shuffle(len(B))

def cross_db_generator():
    for db1_example, db2_example in zip(db1, db2):
        # print(db1_example.numpy(), db2_example.numpy())
        yield db1_example + db2_example


cross_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(cross_db_generator, output_types=(tf.uint8))
cross_db = cross_db.batch(2)

for sample in cross_db:
    print((sample[0].numpy(), sample[1].numpy()))
```